# Regex: repeated matches using start of line

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Say that I would like to replace all `a`s that are after 2 initial `a`s and that only have `a`s in between it and the first 2 `a`s. I can do this in Vim using the (very magic `\v`) regex `s:\v(^a{2}a{-})@<=a:X:g`:

```
aaaaaaaaaaa
```

goes to

```
aaXXXXXXXXX
```

However, why does `s:\v^a{2}a{-}\zsa:X:g` only replace the first occurrence? I.e., giving

```
aaXaaaaaaaa
```

I presume this is because the first match "consumes" the start of the line and the first 2 `a`s such that later matches only are matching on what remains of the line, which never can match the `^` again. Is this true? Or rather what is the most pedagogical explanation?

P.S. This is a minimal example of another problem.

**Edit**

Accepted answer corrected a typo in the original regex (a missing `^`) and its comment answered the question: why can the `^` be "reused" in the lookbehind but not in the `\zs` case? (Ans: lookbehind doesn't consume the match whereas `\zs` does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point here is that `(a{2}a{-})@<=a` matches any `a` (see the last `a`) that is preceded with two or more `a` chars. In NFA regex flavors, it is equal to `(?<=a{2,}?)a`, see [its demo](https://regex101.com/r/P8uw6d/2).

The `^a{2}a{-}\zsa` regex matches the start of string, then two or more `a`s, then discards this matched text and matches an `a`. So, it cannot match other `a`s since the `^` anchors the match at the start of the string (and it does not allow matching anywhere else).

You probably want to go on using a lookbehind construct and add `^` there (if you want to only start matching if the string starts with two `a`s):

```
:%s/\v(^a{2}a{-})@<=a/X/g
```

Comment: Absolutely, that is what I meant! It was an ugly typo of mine! Fixed now. The question is more "why can the `^` be reused in the lookbehind but not in the `\zs` case?"

Comment: @Stalpotaten Because lookbehind pattern is non-consuming. `\zs` only marks the start of the match value after *consuming* the part on the left.